# Are there suitable indexes for this query?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.5

Are there any suitable indexes to support the following query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id
FROM p
INNER JOIN l ON p.id = l.p1_id OR p.id = l.p2_id
WHERE p.s = 'Active'
AND (
    (l.s IN (1, 7) AND l.rd <= CURDATE())
    OR
    (l.s = 2 AND MONTH(l.td) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(l.td) = YEAR(CURDATE()))
)
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE p (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  s varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE l (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  p1_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  p2_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  s int(11) NOT NULL,
  rd date NOT NULL,
  td date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (p1_id) REFERENCES p (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (p2_id) REFERENCES p (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Explain:

```
+--+-----------+-----+----+-------------+---+-------+---+----+--------------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra                                             |
+--+-----------+-----+----+-------------+---+-------+---+----+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1|SIMPLE     |l    |ALL |             |   |       |   |3960|Using where; Using temporary                      |
| 1|SIMPLE     |p    |ALL |PRIMARY      |   |       |   |5091|Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
+--+-----------+-----+----+-------------+---+-------+---+----+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried a number of single column and composite indexes based on the columns in the JOIN and WHERE clauses, and while indexes based on all the relevant columns are used by the DBMS, they don't make a difference to the number of rows evaluated.

Alternatively, could the query be rewritten in a more efficient way?

**Edit:**

Indexing on p.s provided some performance improvement, from 1.4 seconds down to 0.3 seconds.

```
ALTER TABLE p
ADD INDEX (s);
```

New explain:

```
+--+-----------+-----+----+-------------+---+-------+-----+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref  |rows|Extra                                                   |
+--+-----------+-----+----+-------------+---+-------+-----+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 1|SIMPLE     |p    |ref |PRIMARY,s    |s  |32     |const|5058|Using where; Using index; Using temporary               |
| 1|SIMPLE     |l    |ALL |             |   |       |     |3960|Range checked for each record (index map: 0x6); Distinct|
+--+-----------+-----+----+-------------+---+-------+-----+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is further improvement possible?

**Edit 2:**

Explain of Rick James's UNION query with suggested indexes applied:

```
+--+------------+----------+-----+-------------+---+-------+-----+----+------------------------+
|id|select_type |table     |type |possible_keys|key|key_len|ref  |rows|Extra                   |
+--+------------+----------+-----+-------------+---+-------+-----+----+------------------------+
| 1|PRIMARY     |l         |range|srd,std      |srd|7      |     | 733|Using where; Using index|
| 2|UNION       |l         |range|srd,std      |std|7      |     |   2|Using where; Using index|
|  |UNION RESULT|<union1,2>|ALL  |             |   |       |     |    |Using temporary         |
+--+------------+----------+-----+-------------+---+-------+-----+----+------------------------+
```

Some stats:

```
SELECT s, COUNT(*) FROM l GROUP BY s
+-+--------+
|s|COUNT(*)|
+-+--------+
|1|     733|
|2|    3222|
|8|       5|
+-+--------+
      =3960

SELECT s, COUNT(*) FROM p GROUP BY s
+--------+--------+
|s       |COUNT(*)|
+--------+--------+
|Active  |    5059|
|Inactive|      32|
+--------+--------+
             =5091
```

The 8 in l.s is correct, and shouldn't be included in the results of the query above. Even though there are no rows with l.s=7, I need to include that possibility.

The expected result set contains 1144 records.

**Finally:**

Building on Rick James's advice, the following query, coupled with indexes in `p` on `(s, td)` and `(r, td)`, performs as efficiently as I hoped to achieve (~50ms):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id
FROM (
    SELECT p1_id AS id
        FROM l
        WHERE s = 1 AND rd <= CURDATE()
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT p2_id
        FROM l
        WHERE s = 7 AND rd <= CURDATE()
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT p1_id AS id
        FROM l
        WHERE s = 1 AND rd <= CURDATE()
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT p2_id
        FROM l
        WHERE s = 7 AND rd <= CURDATE()
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT p1_id
        FROM l
        WHERE s = 2 AND td >= CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') AND td < CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p2_id
        FROM l
        WHERE s = 2 AND td >= CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') AND td < CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
) x
JOIN p ON p.id = x.id
WHERE p.s = 'Active'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a mess because of `ORs`.

Also, try to avoid hiding columns inside functions, including `MONTH()` and `YEAR()`.  If `l.td` can never be bigger than `CURDATE()`, then change `AND MONTH(l.td) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(l.td) = YEAR(CURDATE())` to `AND l.td >= CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01')` (or some other expression that has `l.td` by itself compared to essentially a compile-time constant)

Let's focus first on this part of the query:

```
SELECT  l.id
    FROM  l
    WHERE  ( l.s IN (1, 7)
              AND  l.rd <= CURDATE()
           )
      OR  (l.s = 2
              AND  l.td >= CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') 
          )
```

Will this give you the same resultset?...

```
SELECT  l.id
    FROM  l
    WHERE  l.s IN (1, 7)
      AND  l.rd <= CURDATE()
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  l.id
    FROM  l
    WHERE  l.s = 2
      AND  l.td >= CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01')
```

Now, will it run faster with these:

```
INDEX(s,rd),
INDEX(s,td)
```

?

Before continuing, we need to know how many rows in each table, and what fraction of `p` is 'active'.  And please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for that `UNION`.

**More**

`INDEX(s)` will be helpful since most are 'active'.

The `UNION`'s explain seems good.  It is probably faster than using `OR`.  So now...  Try to craft

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( ...my UNION...) AS u
    JOIN p ON ...
    WHERE ... active
```

The principle is that we have sped up the `OR`, and gotten the result set down somewhat.  Then the `JOIN` will filter out the few that are not 'active'.

Comment: your translation of the month/year condition is not precise. you are assuming that the td value cannot have a value in the future (e.g. next month).Actually it translates to something similar to `(td>=first_of current_month) and (td<first_of_next_month)`.

Comment: First of next month: `CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

Answer (score 1):

I would check if p.s and l.s really need to be VARCHAR and not ENUM or another FOREIGN KEY to a table with all status' values. That would help a lot in your query, even if it still looks up the same amount of records.

In any case I would add indexes for both p.s and l.s. Indexes for l.rd and l.td could also be added, but that depends on whether these tables are mostly for select or for insert.

Still I find your query a bit strange. Wouldn't you prefer to select from l? Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(l.id)
FROM l
WHERE (
    (l.s IN (1, 7) AND l.rd <= CURDATE())
    OR
    (l.s = 2 AND MONTH(l.td) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(l.td) = YEAR(CURDATE()))
) AND (
    l.p1_id IN (SELECT p.id FROM p WHERE p.s = 'Active')
    OR
    l.p2_id IN (SELECT p.id FROM p WHERE p.s = 'Active')
)
```

That would do the search the opposite way. Would this work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I already found that an index on `p.s` improved performance - see my edit. Indexes on `l.s`, `l.rd` and `l.td` made no difference, individually or in combination. Changing `p.s` to an ENUM had no significant impact on performance. Lastly, I most certainly want to select `p.id`, not `l.id`. Perhaps it just looks strange since I abbreviated the column and table names to obscure the purpose of the tables.

Comment: Using a VARCHAR in p.s instead of an enum or a foreign key to another table should start showing big differences when your table grows BIG. The index should also be much smaller in that case.